# svn question: Moving all .svn directories out of the project directory

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am wondering if there is a way to configure Tortoise SVN to save .svn folders in a directory of my choosing rather than in the directory of the files they refer to. The problem is that in a lot of cases these files get included in builds, copies, and other actions involved in developing an ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical solution to this problem is to use an automated build process to create an official build from your source working copies and exclude these folders from the official builds.  You'll also want to include other source files, project files, and anything else that's part of your development working copy but not needed in deployment.

You'll also want to change the debug flag in your Web.config.  And you'll want to create and run unit tests.  And you may want to run fxcop/stylecop.  And there may be other things.  Having an automated build is very useful.  It seem like a lot of work if all you initially want to do is remove the .svn folders, but in the end, you'll find there's really a lot more you want to do than just that and having it automated is well worth it.

TeamCity is a great commercial product with a free version for supporting automated builds.  Cruise Control .NET also works ok.

http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET

Answer (score 4):

1) Nope. thats the design of svn.

2) But, if you want to checkout a project, say for the purpose of nightly builds and cases where you dont need the versioning information. Then you should use "svn export" command. The difference between checkout and export is that export downloads the directory from the server without all the .svn folders.

Comment: OR move to git or hg. They store versioning information in one directory for the entire project. Not to mention, distributed SCM is so much better than svn.

Comment: The project is very large, it wouldn't be terribly convenient to have to do this every time. Thanks for the answer.